# Autoconf macro for Boost MPI?

Tags: c++, boost, mpi, autoconf, boost-mpi

I'm searching an autoconf macro to use in my `configure.ac` that checks for Boost MPI.

It's not hard to find a couple of them on the Internet but none of the one I tried worked as expected.

What `ax_boost_mpi.m4` do *you* use?

EDIT: I'll explain my requirement better. I need the macro to tell me if Boost MPI is available or not (defining `HAVE_BOOST_MPI`) to store the compiler and linker flags somewhere and to switch the compiler from the nornal c++ compiler to an available mpiCC or mpic++.

If the Boost MPI is not found I'd like to be able to choose if I want to stop the configuration process with an error or continue using g++ without HAVE_BOOST_MPI defined.

As a plus it should define an MPIRUN variable to allow running some checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# ===========================================================================
#
# SYNOPSIS
#
#   AX_BOOST_MPI
#
# DESCRIPTION
#
#   Test for MPI library from the Boost C++ libraries. The macro
#   requires a preceding call to AX_BOOST_BASE, AX_BOOST_SERIALIZATION 
#   and AX_MPI. You also need to set CXX="$MPICXX" before calling the 
#   macro.
#
#   This macro calls:
#
#     AC_SUBST(BOOST_MPI_LIB)
#
#   And sets:
#
#     HAVE_BOOST_MPI
#
# LICENSE
#
#   Based on Boost Serialize by:
#   Copyright (c) 2008 Thomas Porschberg <thomas@randspringer.de>
#
#   Copyright (c) 2010 Mirko Maischberger <mirko.maischberger@gmail.com>
#
#   Copying and distribution of this file, with or without modification, are
#   permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright notice
#   and this notice are preserved. This file is offered as-is, without any
#   warranty.

#serial 1

AC_DEFUN([AX_BOOST_MPI],
[
    AC_ARG_WITH([boost-mpi],
    AS_HELP_STRING([--with-boost-mpi@<:@=special-lib@:>@],
                   [use the MPI library from boost - it is possible to 
                      specify a certain library for the linker
                      e.g. --with-boost-mpi=boost_mpi-gcc-mt-d-1_33_1 ]),
        [
        if test "$withval" = "no"; then
            want_boost="no"
        elif test "$withval" = "yes"; then
            want_boost="yes"
            ax_boost_user_mpi_lib=""
        else
            want_boost="yes"
            ax_boost_user_mpi_lib="$withval"
        fi
        ],
        [want_boost="yes"]
    )

    if test "x$want_boost" = "xyes"; then
        AC_REQUIRE([AC_PROG_CC])
        CPPFLAGS_SAVED="$CPPFLAGS"
        CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS $BOOST_CPPFLAGS"
        AC_MSG_WARN(BOOST_CPPFLAGS $BOOST_CPPFLAGS)
        export CPPFLAGS

        LDFLAGS_SAVED="$LDFLAGS"
        LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS $BOOST_LDFLAGS"
        export LDFLAGS

        LIBS_SAVED="$LIBS"
        LIBS="$LIBS $BOOST_SERIALIZATION_LIB"
        export LIBS

        AC_CACHE_CHECK(whether the Boost::MPI library is available,
                       ax_cv_boost_mpi,
        [AC_LANG_PUSH([C++])
             AC_COMPILE_IFELSE(AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[@%:@include <boost/mpi.hpp>
                                                ]],
                                   [[int argc = 0; 
                                     char **argv = 0;
                                     boost::mpi::environment env(argc,argv);
                                     return 0;
                                   ]]),
                   ax_cv_boost_mpi=yes, ax_cv_boost_mpi=no)
         AC_LANG_POP([C++])
        ])
        if test "x$ax_cv_boost_mpi" = "xyes"; then
            AC_DEFINE(HAVE_BOOST_MPI,,[define if the Boost::MPI library is available])
            BOOSTLIBDIR=`echo $BOOST_LDFLAGS | sed -e 's/@<:@^\/@:>@*//'`
            if test "x$ax_boost_user_mpi_lib" = "x"; then
                for libextension in `ls $BOOSTLIBDIR/libboost_mpi*.{so,a}* 2>/dev/null | grep -v python | sed 's,.*/,,' | sed -e 's;^lib\(boost_mpi.*\)\.so.*$;\1;' -e 's;^lib\(boost_mpi.*\)\.a*$;\1;'` ; do
                     ax_lib=${libextension}
                    AC_CHECK_LIB($ax_lib, exit,
                                 [BOOST_MPI_LIB="-l$ax_lib"; AC_SUBST(BOOST_MPI_LIB) link_mpi="yes"; break],
                                 [link_mpi="no"])
                  done
                if test "x$link_mpi" != "xyes"; then
                for libextension in `ls $BOOSTLIBDIR/boost_mpi*.{dll,a}* 2>/dev/null | grep -v python | sed 's,.*/,,' | sed -e 's;^\(boost_mpi.*\)\.dll.*$;\1;' -e 's;^\(boost_mpi.*\)\.a*$;\1;'` ; do
                     ax_lib=${libextension} 
                    AC_CHECK_LIB($ax_lib, exit,
                                 [BOOST_MPI_LIB="-l$ax_lib"; AC_SUBST(BOOST_MPI_LIB) link_mpi="yes"; break],
                                 [link_mpi="no"])
                  done
                fi

            else
               for ax_lib in $ax_boost_user_mpi_lib boost_mpi-$ax_boost_user_mpi_lib; do
                      AC_CHECK_LIB($ax_lib, exit,
                                   [BOOST_MPI_LIB="-l$ax_lib"; AC_SUBST(BOOST_MPI_LIB) link_mpi="yes"; break],
                                   [link_mpi="no"])
                  done

            fi
            if test "x$link_mpi" != "xyes"; then
                AC_MSG_ERROR(Could not link against $ax_lib !)
            fi
        fi
        LIBS="$LIBS_SAVED"
        CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS_SAVED"
        LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS_SAVED"
    fi
])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of a turnkey solution here, but that doesn't mean one's unavailable.

With some work, you could probably adapt http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_mpi.html#ax_mpi and http://github.com/tsuna/boost.m4 to do what you want.  The former digging up the MPI compiler and the latter checking for Boost MPI.  You'd have to add a Boost MPI check to boost.m4 as it doesn't have one.  You'd have to add your own MPIRUN-searching mechanism.

If you find a solution and/or roll your own, please do share.

Comment: I've rolled my own, and submitted a feature request to the tsuna/boost.m4 project.

Answer (score 0):

This comment is a bit late, but I will add it here so that others searching for the same topic can find it.  I had personally been looking for a function integrated into boost.m4 that defined similar variables as the other boost libraries (BOOST_MPI_LDFLAGS, BOOST_MPI_LIBS).  I finally just added one and submitted a pull request here:

https://github.com/tsuna/boost.m4/pull/50

This uses the MPICXX variable for CXX/CXXCPP if it is already defined (by ax_mpi.m4, acx_mpi.m4, etc), otherwise it uses the existing CXX/CXXCPP.